# C# intercept file reads

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a large bespoke container file (~3TB) in size, and another application that needs to read from it.

However, the application doesn't understand the structure of the container, so I have to convert it first, which means creating another ~3TB file; I'm hoping to streamline this process.

What I'd like to do is to create a file/pipe/something on the file system, and when the other applications reads from it, my application simply returns the correct data from within the container.

I'm not sure if this can be done in C# and I don't really want to have to hook any OS components, so I was thinking that a named pipe might work, but I'm not sure, if anyone has any suggestions or ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: *I don't really want to have to hook any OS components* then it's not possible ... if you wana some hooks you can use **dokan**

Comment: I'll have to take a look into dokan, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't control the consuming application and it expects to be reading from the file system, there may be a way of doing this but it's a fair bit of work.

Recent releases of Windows 10 have included the [Windows Projected File System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/projected-file-system). Windows takes care of all of the file system interception and you just have to be able to answer questions like ["what files are meant to be in this directory?"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/enumerating-files-and-directories) and the like. I believe it's now used for OneDrive and that's one of the intended uses - where the actual files may normally reside in cloud storage rather than locally.

You do have to make file content available [as Windows demands it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/projfs/providing-file-data). The one thing to say though is that it's not an easy job direct from C#. If you're going to try binding to this API, it really helps if you understand a bit of C or C++ too.

Earlier this year I was looking to create a managed binding to this API to make consumption easier from .NET languages. It's not, however, currently in a releasable state. But the basics worked and proves that this is a viable approach.

Once .NET Core 3 is fully released I'll probably dust this off again and make it work well, but for now it's a [WIP](https://github.com/Damien-The-Unbeliever/ProjectedFileSystem)

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I'll take look into that.  Thanks

Comment: @Fildor - pushed, and linked from answer. I haven't looked at it for a few months and don't have the right previews installed at the moment to even confirm it still compiles currently.